# Impossible foods

Tags: wordplay, cipher, word-search

Reveal a message by zigzagging down through the rows, selecting one letter per row.
Then, start again to find a second message.
Then, start again to find a third message.

No letter is used in more than one message.

```
    T W I S T

 S H E P H E R D

     B E E R

    O L I V E

   M U F F I N

    A P P L E

     G Y R O

     S T E W

     S O D A

   F R U I T Y

     B O A R

     F U L L

    B A K E D

   O X T A I L

    F E A S T

    T H I C K

    A R O M A

  P R I V A T E

     C O R E

     S T I R

     S I P S

     M I N T

    B A G E L

    T A B L E

     G H E E

    S C E N T

   H E R B A L

  C U I S I N E

    M E N U S

    S I N G E

      S E T

    V I B E S

   C O F F E E

   F R E N C H

    T A S T Y

    D U T C H

     H E N S

      P I E

    O N I O N

     F I G S

     P O T S

   C H O I C E

    B E A N S

    P E E L S

   C O O K I E

     R I B S

    S A L S A

     B I T E

    B R O T H

     V E A L

    S W E E T

    B U N D T

    P E S T O

    O U N C E

    R A M E N

    C U R E D

    B A C O N

    L U N C H

   I N V I T E

     S A L T

     T U N A

     D I L L

     T E A R

     C H E W

    A G A V E

   W O O D S Y

    P O P P Y

     O K R A

   S A L M O N

    D O N U T

   T H A W E D

     T H I N

     S I D E

    M I N C E

     W I L T

  C A R V I N G

     T H A I

    C O C O A

     T U R N

    D O U G H

     S E E D

    F R I E S

    C U M I N

   P I P I N G

     P O U R

     S A G E

       S Z

        I

        B

        L

        E
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Something that quickly became clear to me:

> The words 'possible' and 'impossible' can be found several times, suggesting that the messages are all quotes containing these words.

The first message I found mainly because I recognized it:

> The only way of discovering the limits of the possible is to venture a little way past them into the impossible. (Arthur C. Clarke)

With those letters out of the way, I was able to find the next (with just a little bit of help from Google to complete the quote.)

> The impossible attracts me, because everything possible has been done and the world didn't change. (Sun Ra)

That leaves the final message, which gave me more trouble than it should have.

> I prefer to talk of impossible things, because of the possible too much is already known. (Silvio Rodríguez)

Comment: You're doing great!  Keep going with #3.  There's more.

Comment: @SlowMagic Got it.